# How to use webview in viewpager?

Tags: webview, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose

I have a horizontal pager in which i use a webview to load urls. I use this on a quiz game i am trying to make. The code for Webview is this.

```
                                        jsInterface = JSInterface(context)
                                    if (question.questionImage == null || question.questionImage == "") jsInterface!!.image =
                                        "" else jsInterface!!.image =
                                        question.questionImage
                                    jsInterface!!.question = question.questionText
                                    jsInterface!!.answer1 = question.answerA
                                    jsInterface!!.answer2 = question.answerB
                                    jsInterface!!.answer3 = question.answerC
                                    jsInterface!!.answer4 = question.answerD
                                    jsInterface!!.correctAnswer = question.correctAnswer
                                    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                                    )

                                    //webViewClient = WebViewClient()

                                    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                                        override fun onPageStarted(
                                            view: WebView?,
                                            url: String?,
                                            favicon: Bitmap?
                                        ) {
                                            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                                            viewModel.dialogLoading(true)
                                        }

                                        override fun onPageFinished(
                                            view: WebView?,
                                            url: String?
                                        ) {
                                            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                                            viewModel.dialogLoading(false)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                                    settings.builtInZoomControls = true
                                    settings.displayZoomControls = false
                                    addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface!!, "Android")
                                    setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
                                    loadUrl(multipleChoiceFile)

                        }.also { webView = it }
                    },
```

below the webview there is a button which is used to check for right answer and navigate to next page:

```
Button(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                onClick = {
                    if (viewModel.questionAnswered.value) {
                        scope.launch {
                            if (pagerState.currentPage == pagerState.pageCount - 1) {
                                //pagerState.animateScrollToPage(pagerState.currentPage + 1)
                                viewModel.onEvent(QuizScreenEvent.OnEndClick)
                            } else {
                                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(pagerState.currentPage + 1)
                            }
                        }
                        viewModel.setQuestionAnswered(false)
                    }
                    else {
                        viewModel.setQuestionAnswered(true)
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = if (viewModel.questionAnswered.value) {
                        if (pagerState.currentPage + 1 == pagerState.pageCount) "END" else "NEXT"
                    } else {
                        "SUBMIT"
                    },
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
```

Each url (index.html file which is the question) loads external css and js file.
The problem is that when i submit first answer and hit next the next pages are not working? I am stack 2 days now. The js file especially not working as expected. Different answer and questions are loading in pages but the main a function checking the right and wrong answer is not triggered. In other words thw js functions not loading properly. Can saomeone help me?